# Closed formula for some dimension

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

This question has a background from representation theory/homological algebra, but I state everything in elementary terms here:

Call an n-CNak an n-tupel $[c_0,c_1,...,c_{n-1}]$ where $c_0=c_1=...=c_{i-1}=a \geq 2$ and $c_i=c_{i+1}=...=c_{n-1}=a+1$ for some $i$ with $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, furthermore $a \leq n+1$.

Example all $3$-CNaks:
{ [ 2, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, 3 ], [ 3, 3, 4 ], [ 3, 4, 4 ], [ 4, 4, 5 ], [ 4, 5, 5 ] }.

We can write CNaks $[a,a,a,....,a+1,a+1,...,a+1]$ for short as $[a,i]$ when $n$ is clear. Here the first $a+1$ appears in position $i$ (note that we start at counting by zero for positions). We view the indices of the $c_i$ mod $n$ so that they are defined for all integers.

A module of an n-CNak is a 2-tupel $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}n \times \{1,2,...,c_{x} \}$. Example: All modules of the 4-Cnak [2,2,2,3] are $(0,1),(0,2),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)$.

Define the first syzygy $O^1(x,y)$of a module $(x,y)$ as $O^1(x,y)=(x+y,c_x-y)$ and the $n$-syzygy $O^n(x,y)$ as $O^n(x,y)=O^1(O^{n-1}(x,y))$ (the zeroth syzygy is the module itself).

Define the dominant dimension $dd(x,y)$ of a module $(x,y)$ as $\inf \{ i \geq 0 | O^i(x,y)=(0,z)$ for some $z \}$.

Define the dominant dimension of n-CNak as the dominant dimension of the module $(i,a)$.

Example for the 4-Cnak $[2,2,2,3]$ or $[2,3]$:
The syzygies of the relevant module $(3,2)$ are $O^1(3,2)=(5,1)=(1,1), O^2(x,y)=(2,1), O^3(x,y)=(3,1), O^4(x,y)=(0,1)$. Thus the dominant dimension is 4 in this case.

**Questions: 
1. Is there are nice closed formula for the dominant dimension in terms of $a,i$ and $n$?

2.Is there a nice way to see when the dimension is even or odd?**

-Here the number of $n$-CNaks with odd dominant dimension for small $n$:
http://oeis.org/A000217

-Here the number of $n$-Cnaks with dominant dimension at least 2:
numer should be equal to $(n-1)^2$.

-Here the number of $n$-Cnaks with dominant dimension at least 3:
http://oeis.org/A002378

In fact one can find a ton of such sequences when counting the dominant dimension with respect to certain things. This leads to the guess that the dominant dimension has another combinatorial/number theoretic secret meaning here.
Here some examples for small n (it displays the n-CNak and after that its dominant dimension)

n=2:
 [ [ 2, 1 ], 2 ],
[ [ 3, 1 ], 1 ].

n=3:
[ [ 2, 2 ], 3 ],
[ [ 2, 1 ], 1 ],
[ [ 3, 2 ], 2 ],
[ [ 3, 1 ], 4 ],
[ [ 4, 2 ], 1 ],
[ [ 4, 1 ], 2 ].

n=4:
[ [ 2, 3 ], 4 ],
[ [ 2, 2 ], 1 ],
[ [ 2, 1 ], 2 ],
[ [ 3, 3 ], 5 ],
[ [ 3, 2 ], 3 ],
[ [ 3, 1 ], 1 ],
[ [ 4, 3 ], 2 ],
[ [ 4, 2 ], 4 ],
[ [ 4, 1 ], 6 ],
  [ [ 5, 3 ], 1 ],
[ [ 5, 2 ], 2 ],
[ [ 5, 1 ], 3 ].

n=5:
[ [ 2, 4 ], 5 ],
[ [ 2, 3 ], 1 ],
[ [ 2, 2 ], 2 ],
[ [ 2, 1 ], 6 ],
[ [ 3, 4 ], 3 ],
[ [ 3, 3 ], 4 ],
[ [ 3, 2 ], 1 ],
[ [ 3, 1 ], 2 ],
[ [ 4, 4 ], 7 ],
  [ [ 4, 3 ], 5 ],
[ [ 4, 2 ], 3 ],
[ [ 4, 1 ], 1 ],
[ [ 5, 4 ], 2 ],
[ [ 5, 3 ], 4 ],
[ [ 5, 2 ], 6 ],
[ [ 5, 1 ], 8 ],
[ [ 6, 4 ], 1 ],
[ [ 6, 3 ], 2 ],
[ [ 6, 2 ], 3 ],
[ [ 6, 1 ], 4 ].

n=6:
[ [ 2, 5 ], 6 ],
[ [ 2, 4 ], 1 ],
[ [ 2, 3 ], 2 ],
[ [ 2, 2 ], 7 ],
[ [ 2, 1 ], 3 ],
[ [ 3, 5 ], 4 ],
[ [ 3, 4 ], 8 ],
[ [ 3, 3 ], 1 ],
[ [ 3, 2 ], 2 ],
  [ [ 3, 1 ], 5 ],
[ [ 4, 5 ], 6 ],
[ [ 4, 4 ], 3 ],
[ [ 4, 3 ], 4 ],
[ [ 4, 2 ], 1 ],
[ [ 4, 1 ], 2 ],
[ [ 5, 5 ], 9 ],
[ [ 5, 4 ], 7 ],
[ [ 5, 3 ], 5 ],
[ [ 5, 2 ], 3 ],
[ [ 5, 1 ], 1 ],
  [ [ 6, 5 ], 2 ],
[ [ 6, 4 ], 4 ],
[ [ 6, 3 ], 6 ],
[ [ 6, 2 ], 8 ],
[ [ 6, 1 ], 10 ],
[ [ 7, 5 ], 1 ],
[ [ 7, 4 ], 2 ],
[ [ 7, 3 ], 3 ],
[ [ 7, 2 ], 4 ],
[ [ 7, 1 ], 5 ].

n=7:
[ [ 2, 6 ], 7 ],
[ [ 2, 5 ], 1 ],
[ [ 2, 4 ], 2 ],
[ [ 2, 3 ], 8 ],
[ [ 2, 2 ], 3 ],
[ [ 2, 1 ], 4 ],
[ [ 3, 6 ], 9 ],
[ [ 3, 5 ], 5 ],
[ [ 3, 4 ], 1 ],
  [ [ 3, 3 ], 2 ],
[ [ 3, 2 ], 6 ],
[ [ 3, 1 ], 10 ],
[ [ 4, 6 ], 3 ],
[ [ 4, 5 ], 4 ],
[ [ 4, 4 ], 7 ],
[ [ 4, 3 ], 1 ],
[ [ 4, 2 ], 2 ],
[ [ 4, 1 ], 8 ],
[ [ 5, 6 ], 5 ],
[ [ 5, 5 ], 6 ],
  [ [ 5, 4 ], 3 ],
[ [ 5, 3 ], 4 ],
[ [ 5, 2 ], 1 ],
[ [ 5, 1 ], 2 ],
[ [ 6, 6 ], 11 ],
[ [ 6, 5 ], 9 ],
[ [ 6, 4 ], 7 ],
[ [ 6, 3 ], 5 ],
[ [ 6, 2 ], 3 ],
  [ [ 6, 1 ], 1 ],
[ [ 7, 6 ], 2 ],
[ [ 7, 5 ], 4 ],
[ [ 7, 4 ], 6 ],
[ [ 7, 3 ], 8 ],
[ [ 7, 2 ], 10 ],
[ [ 7, 1 ], 12 ],
[ [ 8, 6 ], 1 ],
[ [ 8, 5 ], 2 ],
[ [ 8, 4 ], 3 ],
[ [ 8, 3 ], 4 ],
  [ [ 8, 2 ], 5 ],
[ [ 8, 1 ], 6 ].

Comment: I found a solution for the odd/even question. I might post it soon.

Comment: I found an elementary combinatorial answer for question 2 (and its subquestions), which I suspect is different from yours. What annoys me is that I still don't have a good answer to question 1.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi yes the sequences are easy to prove. I have no closed formula in terms of $n,i,a$ when the dominant dimension is even but one using recursion.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi The number $s_{n,k}$ of $n$-CNaks with dominant dimension equal to $k$ should be equal to $max(n-[k/2],0)$ in general.